# How to get a hexbin to plot something other than frequency in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Currently the only type of hexbin plot I know how to create is one that plots frequency. I would like to plot my points with the `colour = to 'a variable'`.

Here is my plot now:

```
ggplot(shotchart, aes(x=V1, y=V2)) + 
stat_binhex(bins = 25, colour = "gray", alpha = 0.7) +
scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("yellow","orange","red")) +
guides(alpha = FALSE, size = FALSE) +
xlim(-10, 100) +
ylim(-10, 110) +
geom_rug(alpha = .2) +
coord_fixed()
```

Here is what my plot looks like:

[image]

I have tried adding color to the `aes`

```
ggplot(shotchart, aes(x=V1, y=V2, colour = class)) + 
stat_binhex(bins = 25, colour = "gray", alpha = 0.7) +
scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("yellow","orange","red")) +
guides(alpha = FALSE, size = FALSE) +
xlim(-10, 100) +
ylim(-10, 110) +
geom_rug(alpha = .2) +
coord_fixed()
```

But the ggplot is still just plotting frequency a frequency of the X and Y variable.

Any help will be appreciated. I am new to using the `ggplot2` package so please let me know if I need to provide further information.

**EDIT**

I have now also tried:

```
ggplot(shotchart, aes(x=V1, y=V2, colour = class)) + 
stat_binhex(bins = 25, alpha = 0.7) +
scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("yellow","orange","red")) +
guides(alpha = FALSE, size = FALSE) +
xlim(-10, 100) +
ylim(-10, 110) +
geom_rug(alpha = .2) +
coord_fixed()
```

This is successful in making the border `colour = class` but it will not fill the who bin to `colour = class`. I tried changing `colours = c("yellow","orange","red"` to `colours = class` but this did not work.

What my plot looks like now.

[image]

Comment: perhaps adding `fill` vs `color` would help

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thank you for your comment. Can you please explain further what you mean by `adding fill vs color`? I tried changing `ggplot(shotchart, aes(x=V1, y=V2, colour = class)) + ` to  `ggplot(shotchart, aes(x=V1, y=V2, fill = class)) +` but this did not work.